# Expressionengine login user from remote through API

Tags: php, expressionengine

I am trying to build a module in Expression engine which will allow users to login through a mobile app.

I have earlier used the EE APIs like channel entries but this is new to me.

I plan to create a module class say 'Userapi' and a method 'login_user' and register an action for this in the actions table. I will get an id say '25' and then i can use the url 'http://mydomain.com/index.php?ACT=25' and that works fine.

The issue is for the mobile development team will install the module, how will they know the action id for the login function. They should not go to the database to check. There should be some method which should provide that action id to them and I am not able to figure out how?

Please help. If there is a better approach I would like to implement that.

**Updated after Peter's answer:**

I am a bit confused. The form (login / registration) would be there on the mobile app. The form will post the data to the expression engine url where the EE plugin is supposed to handle the post data and login or register the user.

In this scenario what is the most appropriate approach. The url is http so its also its a non-secure protocol.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a bespoke (single project use) the Action ID never changes on the install so you could hard code it in the mobile app?

Otherwise you'll need a call to retrieve the Action ID, 2 ways come to mind:

1. Create a tag output function and have it output the Action ID into a template, then you can provide a specific URL to the mobile developers that returns the Action ID.
2. Create an Extension that listens to session_end for a specific URL or query, it can the intercept and return the relevant request:
   http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/session/index.html

To get the Action ID for both approaches:

```
$actionID = $this->EE->functions->fetch_action_id(__CLASS__, 'login_user');
```

You might want to consider utilising secure forms, so get this same code to generate an XID, that can be passed back with the same request (maybe a JSON object), then the mobile login could utilise this in addition to Action ID for improved security.

```
$this->EE->functions->form_declaration($formDetails)
```

Ref: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/reference/functions.html#form-declaration-data-array
Also: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/guidelines/security.html#id13

Also consider not bothering with an additional login/registration layer and just tap into the existing native EE login/registration, which can be simulated in the same way.

Example of using the existing registration: http://www.sidd3.com/stand-alone-member-registration-form-in-expressionengine/

Note:

```
$actionID = $this->EE->functions->fetch_action_id('Member', 'register_member');
```

A similar one can be found for login:

```
$actionID = $this->EE->functions->fetch_action_id('Member', 'member_login');
```

And member logout:

```
$actionID = $this->EE->functions->fetch_action_id('Member', 'member_logout');
```

**Update**:

Secure doesn't mean https, but that the form was posted by a valid source, rather than a hacker!

**Further Clarification**

Let's assume the Mobile dev team are working on the login. They would need a form with username and password inputs, they would also need 2 hidden fields, 1 for XID (security check) and 1 for ACT. And the form would be submitted to the root of the website (e.g. www.mydomain.com).

All you'd need to create is a plugin that generated the hidden fields (or values) for them. This plugin could do the following:

```
$actionID = $this->EE->functions->fetch_action_id("Member", 'member_login');
$formDetails = array('action'     => '',
              'name'           => 'mobile-login',
              'id'             => $this->EE->TMPL->form_id,
              'class'          => $this->EE->TMPL->form_class,
              'hidden_fields'  => array('ACT' => $actionID),
              'secure'         => TRUE
);
return $this->EE->functions->form_declaration($formDetails);
```

If used in a template in your root template group called "mobile-login":

```
{exp:your_plugin_name form_id="my_id" form_class="my_class"}
```

This would then render the following to the template it's used in:

```
<form class="my_class" id="my_id" name="mobile-login" method="post" action="http://www.my-domain.com"> 
    <div class="hiddenFields">
        <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="8b13dcd4afa21fe00065319e92a53d8e72a4f687">
        <input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="15">
        <input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1"> 
    </div>
```

So the Mobile developers can either use as is, or pull out the XID and ACT an include on the form they create.

You don't need another add-on to capture a new ACTion for the actual login, as EE does it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I ve updated my question can you please check and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Updated answer to clarify solution.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the process. There is one glitch. I am not able to output the form in the template. Its outputs nothing. I have printed out the $formDetails array it outputs the array but the value of $form in `$form = $this->EE-functions->form_declaration($formDetails)` is blank

Comment: Its working. Actually there were no visible fields so nothing was visible but the dom has the form with all the hidden fields populated. Thanks a ton.